# PHP ssh2_auth_pubkey_file Callback returned error

Tags: php, key, sftp

I wrote this code:

```
$host = <My Host>;
$port = 22;
$methods = array('hostkey', 'ssh-rsa');
$username = <My User>;
$pub_key = 'c:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\ssh\\UserKeys\\pub_key.pub';
$prv_key = 'c:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\ssh\\UserKeys\\prv_key';

print "<pre>";
var_export(file_get_contents($pub_key));
print "</pre>";
print "<pre>";
var_export(file_get_contents($prv_key));
print "</pre>";

$connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22, $methods); 
if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $username, $pub_key, $prv_key)){
    echo "Ok!!!!\n";
}else{
    echo "Ko!!!!";
}
```

When I run the code it returns:

> Warning: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for 
>   using public key: Callback returned error in....

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880078/ssh2-auth-pubkey-file-authentication-always-fails

Comment: Can you login using that username and key using any SFTP/SSH client from the same machine that runs your PHP code?

Comment: Yes, I can! FileZilla work good!
www-data can access Public and Private key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh2\_auth\_pubkey\_file authentication always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880078/ssh2-auth-pubkey-file-authentication-always-fails)

Comment: How does your two key files look like? Show/describe their structure + Show us FileZilla log file. + Did you try phpseclib library instead?

Comment: phpseclib  work fine , thanks

Comment: it is possible to work with private/public key using phpseclib?

Comment: Note, if you still can't get it working, it might be the key format, I resolved with `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa` ;)